# Formatting date for Tabulator cell to dd/mm/yy

Tags: tabulator

I am using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.6#formatters) for an external JSON source.
The source gives the DOB in this format: `2020-04-16T00:00:00.000+0000`
which I want to convert to `dd/mm/yy`

**I have included the `moment` library**.
I am using this code:

```
{title:"Date of Birth", field:"birthDate", sorter:"date", width:200, sorterParams:{format:"DD/MM/YY"}},
```

But no change is displayed - i just get the original format.

I have also tried this, but it also did not work.

```
    {title:"Date of Birth", field:"birthDate", sorter:"date", width:200, formatter:dateFormatter},


    //custom date formatter
    var dateFormatter = function(cell, formatterParams){
        var value = cell.getValue();

        if(value){
            value = moment(value , "YYYY/MM/DD").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following 2 formats landed up working for me. Kudos to @adrian-klaver for the pointer to option #2

**Option 1:**

```
                {title:"Date of Birth", field:"dob", width:150, formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
                        var value = cell.getValue();
                        value = moment(value).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                        return value;
                    }},
```

**Option 2:**

```
                {title:"Date of Birth", field:"dob", width:150, formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{
                        inputFormat:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii",
                        outputFormat:"DD/MM/YY",
                        invalidPlaceholder:"(invalid date)",
                        timezone:"America/Los_Angeles",
                    }
                },
```

Comment: the above requires luxon to be installed , install with `npm install luxon` and then declare in your app component init, window['luxon'] = luxon where it is imported as `import * as luxon from 'luxon'; `

Answer (score 1):

You need the datetime formatter:

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/format#format-builtin

For your custom formatter you are missing the onRendered argument.